# AMASTY Special Promotions question

Tags: promotions

Using AMASTY Special Promotions add on we are wanting to run a promotion for $50 OFF orders of $150, but it excludes specially priced items. Currently it is working to take off $50 of orders of $150 or more, but even though I selected for it to not include certain product, it still is. Any suggestions?

I currently have it as a "Fixed Amount Discount for Whole Cart"

Comment: It's unlikely that we'll be able to help as this is a third-party module. Hoping that http://magento.stackexchange.com/users/12293/amasty will come along and help, so I won't close this just yet.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you are using any extension or just Magento default rules, please use the "condition" tab, where you can specify products sub-selection like "total amount of products excluding x,y,z greater than 150".

[image: Products without special price]

Then, at the "Actions" tab, please select the discount type you'd like to apply.

If you need further assistance, please post the rule configuration screens or email to the Amasty support - https://amasty.com/contacts